# Html bad formatting?

Tags: javascript, android, html, soap, webview

I'm fixing an old Android app, more exactly a Xibo player: you create a kind of presentation on the website and schedule it on your displays (in that case some Android devices).

I didn't got very good the mechanics yet (since some part of code are obfuscated), so I can't say who creates the files, but there are some html, javascript and raw files (pdf, jpeg, etc) and I know the app uses soap service.

Now the app is working pretty good, but if there is a pdf in the presentation (OK with jpg, bit I didn't try with other files) I see a string on the top of the view (WebView) and a string at the bottom, respectively "GetResourceRespond{resource=“ and "} ;".
I noticed those string at in the html file itself, but if I remove them, I can't see the file (I got a white view instead).

Those string are outside the <. html> tag, first one before <. doctype> and the second one after <. /html>, but I believe this is wrong.
Does somebody have an idea?

This is one html file:

```
    GetResourceResponse{resource=<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Xibo Open Source Digital Signage</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!-- Copyright 2006-2017 Spring Signage Ltd. Part of the Xibo Open Source Digital Signage Solution. Released under the AGPLv3 or later. -->
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, "Trebuchet MS";
        }
        h1, h2, h3, h4, p {
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        #iframe {
            border: 0;
        }
        .cycle-slide p, p.cycle-slide {
            margin-bottom:0;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />


</head>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><body class="ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><body class="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><body class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><body class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><body><!--<![endif]-->
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">var options = {"type":"text","fx":"none","duration":15,"durationIsPerItem":false,"numItems":1,"takeItemsFrom":"start","itemsPerPage":0,"speed":0,"originalWidth":"1920.0000","originalHeight":"1080.0000","previewWidth":0,"previewHeight":0,"scaleOverride":0,"marqueeInlineSelector":".item, .item p"}; var items = ["<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><span style=\"font-size:168px;\"><strong><span style=\"font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;\"><span style=\"color:#FFFFFF;\">Welcome to Xibo<\/span><\/span><\/strong><\/span><\/p>\n\n<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><span style=\"font-size:80px;\"><span style=\"font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;\"><span style=\"color:#FFFFFF;\">Open Source Digital Signage<\/span><\/span><\/span><\/p>\n\n<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><span style=\"font-size:48px;\"><span style=\"color:#D3D3D3;\"><span style=\"font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;\">This is the default layout - please feel free to change it whenever you like.<\/span><\/span><\/span><\/p>\n"];</script> <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="xibo-layout-scaler.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="xibo-text-render.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="xibo-image-render.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() { $("#content").xiboTextRender(options, items); $("body").xiboLayoutScaler(options); $("#content").find("img").xiboImageRender(options); }); </script> </html> ; }
```

Comment: I think that such html is invalid

Comment: Yes, I think the same, but I really have no idea about how to make it right.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, "GetResourceRespond{resource=“ and "} ;" could result from JavaScript, which is allowed inside and after the `<html></html>`. If you don't see more of the JavaScript, it's likely obfuscated with the rest.

Comment: I've edited the post with one html file (sorry for the formatting, I can't do better from smartphone)

Comment: Obviously the outer pattern of the file is:    `GetResourceResponse{ resource=GetResourceResponse{resource=  <!doctype html> [HTML file here] ; }`

This does not look like clean code in any language I know. You may google for the term `GetResourceResponse` to get an idea of whats going on.

Comment: So is it right? But how to hide the strings for the webview? I'm pretty confused

Comment: 1. The content is inserted by JavaScript at the end of the body. You have to analyse the code to see, if all resources are available the script is needing.

2. It the surrounding `GetResourceResponse{ resource=GetResourceResponse{resource= <!doctype html> [HTML file here] ; }` just an accident? 

You speak of ONE HTML file. How about the others. If they all contain this string, it has likely some functionality if the App ever worked.

Comment: All the html files got that:
- with code I see code and file/s
- without code I can't see the file.

Comment: You can't see the file, because there is no content in the HTML body. 

`<body><div id="content"></div><\body>`

JavaScript must be executed to insert content. You may insert some dummy content to get the idea.

Comment: Yes I know a little about html, so how can I let js works, without show that strings on the screen??

Comment: Without basic knowledge of HTML/JS you should just give this job to somebody else. You will not become happy with it.

Comment: The basic knowledges say a js script should be inside a <. script> tag